# Heroku Toolbelt Windows - Rails Console Command History

Tags: windows, heroku, irb

Is it possible to get the Rails console command line history when using the Heroku toolbelt on Windows?

```
heroku run console
```

This is not working on Windows 7 using version 2.33.1.

Comment: It would be helpfull to know what exactly isn't working as expected, what errors you get, what you've tried to solve this and things like that.

Comment: Did you check its online Documents?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
heroku run rails c
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's 6 years later, but I recently released a project for this.

[Archer: Rails console history for Heroku, Docker, and more](https://github.com/ankane/archer)